# Can not call javascript from kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I need to call a javascript function from a span tag on kendo ui grid. I've implemented as below, but it isn't work.
// Kendoui grid

```
c.Template(m => { }).ClientTemplate(@"<a><span class='k-icon k-i-plus hide-row-grid'></span></a>");
```

// Javascript

```
$('.hide-row-grid').click(function () {
        alert('hide button click');
    });
```

Please help me resolve it. Thanks

Comment: Solution may be event delegation.

Comment: Hi @AnoopJoshi, I don't understand your comment, please explain details for me.

Comment: first of all you should enclose the event in $(document).ready(function(){}); If that doesnt work, try with $(document).on("click",".hide-row-grid",function(){});

Comment: Try with this code $(document).on("click",".hide-row-grid",function(){alert('hide button click');});

Comment: I use the code:  $(document).on("click",".hide-row-grid",function(){alert('hide button click');}); and it works. Thanks @AnoopJoshi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe event delegation for binding events to dynamically creating objects,

```
$(document).on("click", ".hide-row-grid", function () {
    alert('hide button click');
});
```